# Custom Percentage Scale

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can someone tell me how I'd go about creating a custom percentage scale for an android app? For example, if I'd like 65 (or below) to be 0% and 315 (or above) to be 100%, and I input 255 it would give me a percentage value based on this scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a mathematical question.

```
if (value < 65) {
    return 0;
}
if (value > 365) {
    return 100;
}
return (value - 65 / (365 - 65)) * 100;
```

Comment: You're much closer to what I wanted but the output isn't correct. Say if the value they entered is 300, that would give me a percentage of 110% using this formula which wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: You're the best, thanks again